# How to transfer orders from Magento 2.4.2-p1 to Magento ver. 2.4.5-p1?

Tags: importexport

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
13 Amasty extensions
```

I have a production Magento 2.4.2-p1 website with 2 stores. *We are having lots of problems with this site which I truly believe might be a combination of using the official Magento Migration tool when we migrated from Magento 1.9.x and issues caused by Amasty extensions.* We were able to sort some of the problems out but certain serious issues persist and I may not be able to resolve these.

I have, therefore, built a brand new Magento ver. 2.4.5-p1 website without using any Migration tools. I tried to use the Export/Import feature to transfer products over. Unfortunately, only about 2/3 of all products transferred while I keep getting Error messages on the rest. I hope to straighten that out and transfer Customers in the same way without using the Magento Migration Tool.

**What would be the best way to transfer orders over? And are there any other tools to help with migrating the remaing 1/3 of products should I not be able to make it work via the Export/Import process?**

---

UPDATED on May 27th, 2022:

Thank you for your suggestion. I'm sure the Firebear ImportExport module is great but it costs $599.00. Does anyone have any positive experience with any other less expensive extensions? I just need to do a one-time job moving Orders from Magento 2.4.2-p1 to Magento 2.4.5-p1.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use something like Firebear ImportExport - install it on both installs and migrate?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm sure the Firebear ImportExport module is great but it costs $599.00. Does anyone have any positive experience with any other less expensive extensions? I just need to do a one-time job moving Orders from Magento 2.4.2-p1 to Magento 2.4.5-p1.

Comment: Any reason you can't just export those tables out using somehting like PHPMYADMIN and import them back in again?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Is there any way you would let me know the steps on how to do that please? Thank you so much.

Comment: All the sales_order tables in the admin. Just export them out via PHPMYADMIN. 

Set it to truncate table before. Insert Ignore. Data only (Not structure).

Export.

Import into new database. Depending on size, may need to import using command line